# Get stuck on php if with captcha confirmation

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, recaptcha

I have a survey website that everyone have their username , password and status. The problem is the status is use to tell PHP that you can do the survey or not. But they have to pass the reCAPTCHA test with correct status (Only people who have status=1 can go). But I get stuck that tell error that I didn't complete the reCAPTCHA even I passed it with green ticks. I have 5 columns on phpMyAdmin are id(A.I. Primary key) , name , username , password and status.

Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once "condb.php"; // use to connect with phpMyAdmin
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['BTN_ENTER']))
{
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=/*my_key*/&response="
.$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $obj = json_decode($response);
    if($obj->success == true)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and status='1' LIMIT 1"; 
        $result=mysqli_query($cn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($cn));
        $num=mysqli_num_rows($result); # count row from array

        if ($num > 0)
        {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['NAME']=$row['name'];
        header('location:index.php');
        }
        elseif ($row['status']=2) {
            echo "You are admin.";
        }elseif ($row['status']=3) {
            echo "Over power!";
        }

    }elseif($obj->success == false)
    {
        header('location:captcha.php');
    }
    else
    {
    header('location:error.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my form code.

```
<form method="POST">
  <div align="center" class="row col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12"
  style="margin:0 auto;">
  <input type="numeric" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username"
  style="width:35%;height:50%" name="username" autofocus required><br>
  <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" 
  placeholder="Password" style="width:35%;height:50%" name="password" 
  autofocus required><br>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<!--my_key-->"></div>
<br><br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="BTN_ENTER"
style="height:50%;width:20%;">ตกลง</button>
<br><br>

<p style="font-size:32px;color:#66ff33;"><
        <span><a href="https://www.facebook.com"
        class="btn btn-warning btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right">
        Have problem? Contact me</a></span></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong from your code--can you verify you're getting the JSON response you're expecting here ` $obj = json_decode($response);`

Comment: I got it somewhere from some topic in this website. Before , I had a static password on php command and I had reCAPTCHA confirmation. ` $obj =json_decode($response);` was working well. But when I have dynamic login credentials from phpMyAdmin , it can't send respone of reCAPTCHA . @Alan

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.